# How do I implement/convert an existing pure three.js project as a component into a next.js project?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, next.js

I have this little Three.js Project, which I would now like to implement as a React component in my Next.js project.

I have read a lot, tried it with the useRef and useEffect hooks, but always end up with a black canvas.

I have tried to convert my project according to the instructions from this post (https://therohanbhatia.com/blog/integrating-three-js-with-react/) it also works, but my materialArray is not rendered.

Can anyone spot a bug?

```js
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

import px from './cubemap/px.jpg';
import nx from './cubemap/nx.jpg';
import py from './cubemap/py.jpg';
import ny from './cubemap/ny.jpg';
import pz from './cubemap/pz.jpg';
import nz from './cubemap/nz.jpg';

let scene, camera, renderer, skyboxGeo, skybox, controls;

let images = [px, nx, py, ny, pz, nz];

function createMaterialArray() {
  const materialArray = images.map((image) => {
    let texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(image);

    return new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      map: texture,
      side: THREE.BackSide,
    });
  });
  return materialArray;
}

function animate() {
  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

export default function Universe() {
  const cubeRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      55,
      window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
      45,
      30000,
    );

    const materialArray = createMaterialArray();

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    cubeRef.current.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    skyboxGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10000, 10000, 10000);
    skybox = new THREE.Mesh(skyboxGeo, materialArray);
    scene.add(skybox);

    controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.enabled = true;
    controls.minDistance = 100;
    controls.maxDistance = 1500;
    controls.autoRotate = true;
    controls.autoRotateSpeed = 1.0;

    camera.position.set(1200, -250, 200);

    animate();
  }, []);

  return <div ref={cubeRef}></div>;
}
```

Comment: I don't want anyone to do the work for me either, I just need a hint, maybe someone sees a bug in my code.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Have you tried creating the materials without textures.. maybe just colours.. to see if it works? Have you tried making use of the TexureLoader.load callback (second parameter)?